# jQuery live check if input has value

Tags: jquery

How can I live check if an input has value using jQuery?

```
if ($("#reference").filter(function() { return $(this).val(); }).length > 0) {
  //..
}
```

That only checks at page load, how can I check when the user changes the value in `#reference` or leaves it blank at all?

Comment: explain what `live check` means.

Comment: What do you mean by real time?

Comment: Bind relevant event, e.g: `$("#reference").on('input', function(){if(this.value){...}});`. But just sounds like you could use `required` attribute and CSS pseudo class `:valid`, depending your use-case

Comment: @Hitmands Not only checking on page load, but everytime a user change the input field value.

Comment: @Jerrald So you are loooking for event... But again, sometimes CSS is enough: http://jsfiddle.net/3v5ajmcs/

Comment: @A.Wolff The story is, I want to display a overlay over a few options which will become unusable when `#reference` input has value. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jerrald It depends HTML markup

Comment: @Jerrald, check my updated answer. Is that what you need? If not, then your question is incomplete/unclear and you should improve it.

Answer (score 5):

Just use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method so that you can handle events on the objects which are added dynamically (if loaded in live) like this:

> - You should use `.on('change')` event in case of `select` fields.
> - You should use `.on('input')` event in case of `input` fields.

```js
$(function(){

  
    $('body').on('change', "#mySelect", function() {
      var value = $(this).val();

      console.log('Selected Value: ', value);
    });
  
    $('body').on('input', "#myInput", function() {
      if($(this).val().length) {
        var hasVal = true;
      } else {
        var hasVal = false;
      }
      console.log('Input has value (true / false): ', hasVal + " (" + $(this).val() + ")");
    });
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="a">Select A</option>
    <option value="b">Select B</option>
    <option value="c">Select C</option>
    <option value="d">Select D</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="text" id="myInput">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why you use `event delegation` here?

Comment: beacause, if an element is added dynamically into the document's body, then it will help jQuery to find that element after adding of that element! Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Comment: And where is the relation with che current question?

Comment: As according to OP's question title, he/she wants to does these operation in live (dynamically), which according to my understanding is that the initialization of the elements added after the first initialization in `.on('ready')`

Answer (score 1):

input fields have `change` event, you can listen for it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $field = $("#reference");
  
  
  $field.on('change', function() {
    var value = $field.val();
    
    console.log('do your validation with ', value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="reference" />
```

**Just a Note**

`jQuery(..).filter` should be used to reduce the jQuery wrapped set, but, `id`s are thought to indicate a unique dom element, so, filter is completely needless.

1. `$('#reference').val();`

Answer (score -1):

```
  $( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
     alert( "user is typing" );
  });
```

alert will show if user is typing something.In this way you can lively check value entered by user.

```
$( "#target" ).keyup(function() {
     if($(this).val()=="something")
     {
      #your code go here
     }

  });
```

Comment: @ArunSivan If user pastes value using mouse, keyup event isn't fired. Use instead `input` event